# Static Sound in Earphones

Tags: settings, audio

There's a low static sound in the earphones when nothing is playing.

I tried messing with `alsamixer` and it seems to be the headphone mic boost setting, but I can't use `alsactl store` to save it or anything.

Is there another way to save the settings on startup so that this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 1):

After you change your alsa settings you just need

```
sudo alsactl store
```

To store them

Comment: this doesn't work after reboot for some reason, do you have an idea of why?

Comment: Could you tell us which version of OS you have? Maybe alsactl doesn't work well on all linux distros. It works fine with elementaryOS on my virtual machine (Loki, 0.4.1)

Comment: uname -r brings up 4.10.0-37-generic, which seems to correspond with your version, what else could be the issue?

Comment: I checked it again, just to be sure, sudo alsactl store works fine for me after rebooting.
My os brings up '4.4.0-103-generic' after uname -r, so try a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y` just to be sure and try store it again. You could also re-install alsa, looks like your last resort, see [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1537375)